# Slim Framework how to capture route parameter by Name in interceptor

Tags: php, slim

I'm using v2 of Slim framework. Most of the APIs are of the format below:

https://abcXX.com/:version/customer/:CustomerID/XXX/....

So almost all of the APIs have :version and :CustomerID which is provided in the URL.

I'm writing a hookup like so, and wanted to know if there is any way to globally intercept it in hookup function

```
public function call()
{

    $this->app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', array($this, 'onBeforeDispatch'));
    $this->next->call();
}

public function onBeforeDispatch()
{
    $this->app->is_development_environment = IS_DEVELOMPENT_ENVIRONMENT;
    $route_params = $this->app->router()->getCurrentRoute()->getParams();
    $param_version = ???
}
```

I don't know how to get the :version's value from URL parameters. If I could do that, I'd be able to do some global handling at the very top, instead of having to write the code in each API handler function.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Did you consider writing a [middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/middleware/)?

Comment: I did @Nima. However, I'd want to avoid writing a middleware for each and every route. I already have over 400 APIs. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You can use `$app->add()` to add a middleware to the application (instead of a specific route). Read more [here](https://docs.slimframework.com/middleware/how-to-use/).

Comment: How would I read the argument :version inside of it? If you notice my above code snippet, its actually a middleware which I add to app. I'm confused how to get the argument :version (and similarly :customerID)

Comment: @nima: Would this do the trick?

$route_params = $this->app->router()->getCurrentRoute()->getParams();

Comment: You did not mention which class you put `call` and `onBeforeDispatch` in, and you did not mention what is inside `$route_params` after you try to extract route parameters. Anyway, I posted an answer, I hope I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend avoiding hooks for determining which version of your API is being called. Consider [grouping routes](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/groups/) instead.
And I suggest using middlewares instead of hooks unless you really need hooks, they are different in nature.

Anyway, if you want to use hooks, here is an example of how to do it:

```
<?php
require_once ('../vendor/autoload.php');

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', function() use($app){
    $params = $app->router()->getCurrentRoute()->getParams();
    // Use $params['version'] to do what you want
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($params);
    print "</pre>";

});

$app->get('/:version/hello/:name', function ($version, $name) {
        print "Hello, " . $name;
});

$app->get('/:version/customer/:CustomerID/XXX', function($version, $customerId){
    print "Customers route";
});

$app->run();
```

Now if you open `<host address>/2.1/hello/foo` or `<host address>/2.1/customer/1000/XXX` you see in both cases you see `['version'] => 2.1` in `$params`.
But if you go with this approach, I think you should define all your route callbacks to accept a `$version` as their first parameter, which is absolutely unnecessary and redundant and makes code manipulation harder. But if you group routes, then you'll have something like:

```
$app->group('/2.1', function () use ($app {
    $app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {});
    $app->get('/customer/:CustomerID/XXX', function($customerId){});
});
```

which is cleaner and does not need extra effort.

Answer (score -1):

Use Callback Function or Make a function to get params like it :-

```
$app->get('/books/:one/:two', function ($one, $two) {
    echo "The first parameter is " . $one;
    echo "The second parameter is " . $two;
});
```